# Is Java Batch (JSR 352) part of the SE JDK ? (BatchRuntime returns NULL for Joboperator)

Tags: java, jsr352

I have written a Java batch application using the JSR352 implementation from JavaSE. I have a Reader, Processor and Writer.

Since am running this java app from console in a JavaSE environment, I use the following code in my `main(String[] args)` method to start the job.

```
final JobOperator jobOperator = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();
jobOperator.start("Job.xml", null);
```

but, the getJobOperator() returns NULL and get the following error message

> WARNING: javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime The ServiceLoader was unable
>   to find an implemenation for JobOperator. Check classpath for
>   META-INF/services/javax.batch.operations.JobOperator file.

Should I write any implementation of the JobOperator interface ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `javax.batch.*` APIs, though part of the EE 7 platform, were designed to be usable in SE (they don't inherently require a full EE platform).  However, they are not designated as part of the SE platform, so they are not going to be part of a JDK.   You'd need to use a Java Batch implementation, such as [SpringBatch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/), or the [Reference Implementation](https://github.com/WASdev/standards.jsr352.jbatch).

Comment: this java batch job will be finally deployed to Websphere but, during development and in certain conditions, i wanted to be able to run in as a java console application rather than having to deploying to a JEE container and trigger it via REST interfaces.

Comment: >You'd need to use a Java Batch implementation<   sorry, i did not fully understand. Does this mean that, on top of the javax.batch APIs , i need to use SpringBatch or import the jars of the reference implementation project (which will have the JobOperator implementation) ?

Comment: i already have the javaee-api-7.0.jar  in my project classpath. I thought that should be sufficient.

Comment: If you're planning on targeting WebSphere Liberty then I'd look at ways to run the job within a minimal Liberty server.  You could do something like run the job automatically on server start through a startup bean.  Liberty can start in a few seconds, so it's not like the "server" adds a lot of overhead.   Another nice option is the WebSphere Development Tools Batch  (Eclipse-based) tooling.   Still, there are pros and cons with each approach.   Would be happy to discuss more if you're interested, but I think we should leave this question behind and use a new, different question.

Comment: Liberty Server is going to be our production server. I was looking for a simpler way to run the program during development because of cost/license limitations in making Liberty available to entire team.

Comment: as suggested, i have initiated a different question to be specific on the topic of ability to run java batch in SE environment  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239289/how-to-run-java-batch-jsr352-in-java-se-environment

Comment: Let me just close this by noting that, at the time of this writing (Sep. 2017), Liberty is free for development.  See https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/websphere-application-server-everyone/